# Promising not to modify arguments in a Ruby function

Tags: ruby, immutability

Ruby allows you to state that a variable should not be modified by starting its name with an uppercase letter. Can you do this for formal function arguments too?

The interpreter should warn you if the value is instead modified.

As valid example:

```
def append(Constant xs, x)
     xs + x
end
```

An invalid example:

```
def append(Constant xs, x)
     xs += x
end
```

Another valid example:

```
def shift(Constant x)
     xs.first + xs.all_but_first
end
```

Another invalid example:

```
def append(Constant xs, x)
     xs.shift!
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) the object.

> Prevents further modifications to obj. A RuntimeError will be raised
>   if modification is attempted. There is no way to unfreeze a frozen
>   object.

Example:

```
def meth a,b
    a,b = a.clone.freeze, b.clone.freeze
    a[:d] = 10  # Not allowed
end

meth({:a=> 10},"World")
#=> something.rb:3:in `meth': can't modify frozen Hash (RuntimeError)
```

As pointed in comments by @Jorg, to avoid the side effect, we may have to clone the parameter before freezing it.

Also note that you can assign new values to parameters `a` and `b` even if they are frozen, as assignment does not mutate the existing frozen objects - those assignments will not be visible outside the method.

---

Similarly, if you try to modify `b`:

```
b.replace("xyz")
```

will result in error:

```
something.rb:3: in `replace': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Umm. This is exactly the opposite that the OP is asking about. You *are* modifying the argument: you are freezing it. If I pass you an object and then want to do other things with it, I can't, because it is now frozen.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I thought OP needs a mechanism to disallow modification to arguments - `freeze` lets one do that - instead of warning, it is throwing error that's one difference with OP's expectation.  I see what you mean though - the effect of `freeze` is visible outside the function.  Do we need to clone the parameter and freeze it? It is still not perfect though as we need deep cloning!

Comment: Ah. It hadn't occurred to me to interpret the question that way. They way I read it, the OP wants a mechanism that allows the author of a method to promise to the caller of the method that he won't mutate and/or re-bind arguments. (It's not clear which one of the two he is talking about. His analogy with constants suggests re-binding, which is trivial, because Ruby is pass-by-value and thus re-binding is impossible anyway.) Basically mark a parameter as `const`, and have the language complain if you modify it.

Comment: OTOH: if he's *not* talking about re-binding but about mutation, then having the language complain is impossible: the language would have to figure out which methods mutate the receiver and which don't, and this Purity Analysis is well-known to be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I added an example in hope to clarify, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Caridorc: so, you are asking about re-binding. In that case, the answer is trivial: since Ruby is pass-by-value you cannot do that anyway, regardless of any special annotation.

Comment: @Caridorc: In other words: there is nothing for the interpreter to warn about, because the situation you want to warn about cannot possibly happen anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag True, but what if a `!` method is called like in the other example I added?

Comment: @Caridorc: Well, as I already wrote several times, both in my own answer and in the comments to this answer, this is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem and thus impossible. But now I am confused again: so, you are *not* talking about re-binding? But then what is the analogy with constants all about? You ask about a feature analogous to constants, and this is *exactly* analogous to constants: you cannot re-bind, but you can mutate.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for being so patient, I think I now understand. A constant may be modified (like `X << "foo"` where I am putting "foo" inside X), but you may not rebind it (like `X = 5` after `X=1`). People should not mutate arguments passed to functions without mentioning it in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

> Ruby allows you to state that a variable should not be modified by starting its name with an uppercase letter. Can you do this for formal function arguments too?
>
> The interpreter should warn you if the value is instead modified.

I think you are confused. Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. You simply cannot modify the binding of method parameters in the caller's scope:

```
def foo(bar)
  bar = 'something else'
end

baz = "I won't change."

foo(baz)

baz
# => "I won't change."
```

To take the example added to the question:

```
# valid
def append(xs, x)
  xs + x
end

xs, x = 'Hello ', 'World'

append(xs, x)
# => 'Hello World'

xs
# => 'Hello '

# invalid
def append(xs, x)
  xs += x
end

xs, x = 'Hello ', 'World'

append(xs, x)
# => 'Hello World'

# as you can see, xs wasn't modified, since Ruby is pass-by-value:
xs
# => 'Hello '
```

What you *can* do, of course, is mutate the object:

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.replace('Hah! Of course you will!')
end

baz = "I won't change."

foo(baz)

baz
# => 'Hah! Of course you will!'
```

Note that this exactly equivalent to your constant analogy:

```
Baz = "I won't change"

Baz = 'something else'
# warning: already initialized constant Baz
```

but:

```
Baz = "I won't change"

Baz.replace('Hah! Of course you will!')
# no warning

Baz
# => 'Hah! Of course you will!'
```

As a *caller*, you can do one of two things:

1. [Copy](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-clone) the object you pass in, so that you keep an unmodified copy, in which case the method can do whatever it wants without harming you.

   ```
   foo(bar.clone)
   ```
2. [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-freeze) the object you pass in, so that the method cannot modify it (but it might fail if it wants to).

   ```
   foo(bar.freeze)
   ```

As a method *author*, there is no way to communicate to either the caller or the language that you don't intend to mutate the arguments. Note, however, that mutating the arguments is considered extremely bad style, and in fact, I cannot name a single method either in the core lib, the stdlib, any code I have encountered, or any code I have written, even as a beginner.

So, in general you can assume that if the documentation doesn't mention it, then the method doesn't mutate the arguments, and conversely, that if the method *did* mutate the arguments, there would be a big fat warning to that effect in the documentation.

Note that having the language check that you don't modify an argument is simply impossible. You are just calling methods. How can the language know which methods modify the object and which don't? It would have to figure out whether a method can have any sort of externally observable side-effect on the internal state of the object or not. This, however, is equivalent to solving the [Halting Problem](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and thus impossible.